# Java Deflater Equivalent in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java

I'm trying to consume a web service that requires message sent to be compressed. The current implementation is done in Java, however, I want to port it over to Javascript. The compression works as follows:

```
String params = "hello";

byte[] bytes = params.getBytes();

ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bytes.length);    
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
byte[] out = null;
int len;

Deflater compress = new Deflater();
compress.setInput(bytes);
compress.finish();
while(!compress.finished()) {
     len = compress.deflate(buffer);
     bao.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
out = bao.toByteArray(); 

//Output: [120, -100, -53, 72, -51, -55, -55, 7, 0, 6, 44, 2, 21]
```

I've tried using various inflate/deflate libraries like [Zlib](https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js/blob/master/README.en.md)/[Pako](https://github.com/nodeca/pako) without any success:

```
function stringToUint(string) {
    var charList = string.split(''),
    uintArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < charList.length; i++) {
        uintArray.push(charList[i].charCodeAt(0));
    }
    return new Uint8Array(uintArray);
}  

var bytes = stringToUint('hello'); 
var compressed = pako.deflate(bytes); 

//Output: [120, 156, 203, 72, 205, 201, 201, 7, 0, 6, 44, 2, 21]
```

Comparing outputs:

```
Java Output: [120, -100, -53, 72, -51, -55, -55, 7, 0, 6, 44, 2, 21]
JS   Output: [120,  156, 203, 72, 205, 201, 201, 7, 0, 6, 44, 2, 21]
```

Comment: well I guess the `U` in `Uint8Array` means unsigned, so why not try the signed version https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/int8Array

Comment: as far as byte data goes, those two results are identical - when working with compressed data like this, it's actually unusual to use signed bytes, so, my way of looking at it is that your Java output is *wrong* (except that it's identical at the byte level, so, there's no problem)

Comment: @ScaryWombat It seems like the compression returns an unsigned byte array. When I create a signed int array with Int8Array(compressed), the output seems to match now. Cheers!

Comment: @mildse7en Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyones help, it appears the byte data was the same, it I just needed to convert it to a signed array.